# All tasks in Task scheduler are going to queued state when triggered

Tags: windows, windows-server-2019, task-scheduler

recently we have a strange problem with scheduled tasks on Windows server 2019 with RDS role installed. 6 servers were restored from 3 months old backup, joined into the AD domain again and working as session hosts correctly, but none of the tasks in Task scheduler (which ran previously and are running on other SH's which weren't restored) is working no more.

When you run the task manually, everything is working ok, but when you set it to some time, it state turn to Queued and don't execute. We tried to create new tasks, delete all tasks and create brand new, but nothing helped. It's not a problem of task settings, so please don't advise to run new instance in parallel or something similar simple. The same settings are working on the servers which weren't restored.

We tried to look in the registry and in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup\State
ImageState is value IMAGE_STATE_COMPLETE
and in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\Setup\ChildCompletion\audit.exe has value 0 and oobebeldr.exe is set to 3.

Servers are configured and customers are working on them, so reinstall is the last option. Will sysprep without generalize help here? Or something else? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Import the HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Notifications folder from a working server (back it up first just in case). Then reboot the server and it should work.

Comment: "Import the HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Notifications folder from a working server (back it up first just in case). Then reboot the server and it should work." Wow, such a genius, thanks so much!! We got the same weird issue on a Windows Server 2012 R2 after upgraded to 2019, its 'Windows Server Backup' won't launch with schedule task, whatever we tried won't fix, and it is all good now, thanks again 'Milo666'!